# Can ClamAV detect CSV Injection?

Tags: antivirus, injection, csv

I'm allowing users to upload CSV files. Other users can download these files. I'm aware that CSV could be [an attack vector](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection).

Would a ClamAV (or other AV) scan offer protection against such a file?

Any scan would happen only after validating the MIME type.

Comment: Have you already tried it yourself? Or searched in the ClamAV documentation?

Comment: The question is also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067124/can-clamav-detect-csv-injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ClamAV has, as far as I know, no specific detection features for CSV files. CSV injection is not a vulnerability that an AV would resolve directly. Instead, an AV may detect known malicious macro payloads that were injected into a file, regardless of the file type.

If you want to know about specific detection features, I suggest talking to the ClamAV maintainers. For now, I recommend following OWASP's advice on filtering: do not allow any cell to start with `-`, `+`, `=`, or `@`.

Comment: I found you need to bypass the following characters: '=', '+', '-', '@', '|', '%'. Otherwise your filter can be bypassed. See: https://hackerone.com/reports/223999

Comment: @Refineo Good to know.